# Fastest StringBuilder Append of integer

Tags: c#, .net

Append integer to StringBuilder with minimum amount of allocations. Is there a faster way?

```
    public static void AppendInvariant(this StringBuilder builder, int value)
    {
        // Deal with negative numbers
        if (value < 0)
        {
            builder.Append('-');
            uint uint_value = uint.MaxValue - ((uint)value) + 1; //< This is to deal with Int32.MinValue
            AppendInvariant(builder, uint_value);
        }
        else
        {
            AppendInvariant(builder, (uint)value);
        }
    }

    public static void AppendInvariant(this StringBuilder builder, uint value)
    {
        if (value == 0)
        {
            builder.Append('0');
            return;
        }

        // Pad out space for writing.
        int length = UintLength(value);
        builder.Append('0', length);
        length = builder.Length;

        uint tmp_value;
        do
        {
            tmp_value = value;
            value /= 10;
            builder[--length] = (char)('0' + (tmp_value - value * 10));
        } while (value > 0);
    }

    private static int UintLength(uint i)
    {
        if (i < 100000)
        {
            if (i < 10) return 1;
            if (i < 100) return 2;
            if (i < 1000) return 3;
            if (i < 10000) return 4;
            return 5;
        }
        else
        {
            if (i < 1000000) return 6;
            if (i < 10000000) return 7;
            if (i < 100000000) return 8;
            if (i < 1000000000) return 9;
            return 10;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `builder[--length] = (char)('0' + (tmp_value - value * 10));`
Without allocations, you say? :)

Comment: @john Yes you are right, there will be the StringBuilder buffer allocation, but I will accept that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following implementation is approximately 2 times faster.

It does that by minimizing the `StringBuilder` calls by using a small 100 element pre allocated string table

```
private static readonly string[] UIntPairStrings =
    Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(n => n.ToString("00")).ToArray();
```

and also minimizes the number of divisions by processing the input value in 2 digit pairs from higher to lower (to compensate the lack of storage). This way the operation performs no more than 5 `Append` calls.

```
private static readonly uint[] UIntPairScales = { 100000000, 1000000, 10000, 100 };

public static void AppendInvariant(this StringBuilder builder, uint value)
{
    bool next = false;
    foreach (var scale in UIntPairScales)
    {
        if (value >= scale)
        {
            uint pair = value / scale;
            if (!next && pair < 10)
                builder.Append((char)('0' + pair));
            else
                builder.Append(UIntPairStrings[pair]);
            value -= pair * scale;
            next = true;
        }
        else if (next)
        {
            builder.Append("00");
        }
    }
    if (!next && value < 10)
        builder.Append((char)('0' + value));
    else
        builder.Append(UIntPairStrings[value]);
}
```